how to secure firebase googleService.plist from iOS and googleService.json from Android
There is a concern raised by security team that API_KEY is exposed from googleService.plist from iOS and googleService.json from Android. I personally feel that exposing this file is not an issue. But is there any way to secure any plist file from iOS and .json file from android.

It's not a security problem.  That API key is necessarily public information and can't be hidden completely.  It's a waste of effort to even try.

when hackers want some information from your application. They can use some decompilation method.
I think you should learn about some method prevent code reverse translation.
You can reference it here : link
